# Why can't GCC's typeof() be stringified?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, stringification

I'd like to print the type that typeof() outputs, but typeid is only available in C++. Why can't I use stringification to get the name of this type?

```
#define GET_STRING(s) #s

#define example(input)                              \
    do {                                            \
        char test[20] = GET_STRING(typeof(input));  \
        printf(test);                               \
    }                                               \
    while (0)                                       \
```

This would print out "typeof()" with input stringified inside. Why does the preproccessor stringify before typeof() is handled? Is there a way to override this behavior?

You can stringify types directly if they are passed like GET_STRING(int), so using typeof() should have the same behavior.

Comment: `typeof` is handled by the preprcoessor? How so?

Comment: Preprocessor knows nothing about types.

Comment: Ok, so then gcc handles it before sending it to the preprocessor? It would have to for "typeof(x) var = y" to compile. If that's the case, why does it not stringify?

Comment: Why before? You are making one unbased assumption after another. The compiler is handling it after preprocessing. You can examine the preprocessor output here: https://godbolt.org/z/jEav76zWo

Comment: `typeof(x) var = y` works because the compiler knows the type of `x` and is designed to process `typeof(x)` as that type. It does not involve preprocessing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a false premise.

Comment: Preprocessing comes first, *before* the `typeof` operation is evaluated.  `GET_STRING(typeof(input))` expands to `"typeof(input)"`, which is what gets copied to `char_test`.

Comment: I'm trying to learn here? Closing the question helps no one.
The whole point of this site is to ask questions. 
I'm not making assumptions, I'm merely seeing if my thought-process was correct.
Thanks, @JohnBode, for giving an informative and non-condescending answer.

Comment: Translation phases are a large topic. [Some introductory reading here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases).

Comment: @KylePonikiewski: If you are interested in helping people, then enter a new question or rephrase this one to ask how GCC handles `typeof(something)` and whether the preprocessor is involved. Leaving the question open with a false premise is not helpful because it presents misleading information to future readers. Closing bad questions improves Stack Overflow.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I've updated the question and some of its contents to remove any inaccuracies. If someone else has this same question, now they know it's not possible.

Comment: Using `typeof()` in the call to `GET_STRING()` behaves exactly like supplying `int` or any other token sequence — the value passed is stringified.  The `typeof` operator is not recognized by the preprocessor as anything special.  It is handled later in the translation process, long after the preprocessor has completed its work.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the preproccessor stringify before checking typeof()?

There is this "pre" prefix in "preprocessor", it means "before". The preprocessor works before most everything else. [Here](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2p1) is the ordered list of translation phases. Note *"Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded"* comes under #4, and *"Each preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens are syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated as a translation unit"* under #7.

> Is there a way to override this behavior?

No.

> You can stringify types directly if they are passed like GET_STRING(int), so using typeof() should have the same behavior.

The behaviour of the compiler is governed by the language standard, rather than by nebulous wishes of the users. You should quote the standard before making an assertion about what a compiler should or should not do. If you don't like what the standard says, you can write a proposal to amend it and wait for it to be accepted (but I wouldn't hold my breath).

[Here](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.2p2) is what the standard says about stringifying:

> [...] the original spelling of each preprocessing token in the stringizing argument is retained in the character string literal [...]

The original spelling of the `typeof` token in your program is "typeof", so that's what gets inside the string literal.